# Dropbox synchronizing every time I press a key in Kate

Tags: kde, sync, dropbox, kate

I've just noticed Dropbox will synchronize a file every time I press a key in Kate(the text editor).

This behavior does not cause problems but it is annoying to say the least.

Is this caused by Dropbox or by some behavior in Kate? And how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to the backup files which *Kate* creates regularly.

You might check if the described behaviour stops when changing parameters under `Settings - Configure Kate - Editor Component - Open/Save`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known and confirmed bug, since at least three of us can confirm it. It looks to be an Ubuntu-specific thing, since the bug was apparently squashed long ago. Follow up here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=258897